# CQWP for set of libraries (instead of items)

Tags: document-library, content-type, content-query-web-part, library

I have a Team Collaboration site which has multiple document libraries. I have created a custom content type, so the team members can add more libraries in future.

Since the set of document libraries is not fixed and is subjected to change (team may decide to remove two existing libraries and add three new ones), is there a way to create a CQWP, which fetches the list of libraries instead of the list of items in those libraries?

In other words, I need to create a custom page which holds "Add new document" for every library created with a certain content type.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a CQWP you can choose whether it gets files from across a site collection, from every site below specific url or from a specific library.

In this case it sounds like you could use either of the first two options and then refine the query to use your custom content type.  This will then get any documents with that content type, even if they are from new libraries.

I am a bit confused by what you mean by Add new document though - CQWP is used to display content, not to add new?

Comment: I have CQWP at other places to get files across the site collection based on the content type. So, this is not my question..

Comment: How to fetch **create new document** link for each library created with certain content type?

Comment: CQWP is used to roll up information from lists. I don't think there is any way of adding "Create new document link". You may have to do a custom development for that.

Comment: You can create links using createNewDocumentWithProgID() which allows you to specify a document template and destination save library.  You could combine this with some object model javascript/jQuery but there is no web part that I am aware of.